# Probability density from COS method too sensitive to truncation range

Tags: option-pricing, density

I have a long-standing confusion around the truncation range of the COS method proposed by Fang and Oosterlee because I find that the results are highly volatile given the different truncation ranges.

To be more specific, given the following three truncation ranges (which I am aware is merely a rule of thumb):
$$
[a_{2}, b_{2}]:=\left[\kappa_1-L \sqrt{\kappa_2}, \quad \kappa_1+L \sqrt{\kappa_2}\right],
$$
$$
[a_{4}, b_{4}]:=\left[\kappa_1-L \sqrt{\kappa_2+\sqrt{\kappa_4}}, \quad \kappa_1+L \sqrt{\kappa_2+\sqrt{\kappa_4}}\right],
$$
and
$$
[a_{6}, b_{6}]:=\left[\kappa_1-L \sqrt{\kappa_2+\sqrt{\kappa_4 + \sqrt{\kappa_{6}}}}, \quad \kappa_1+L \sqrt{\kappa_2+\sqrt{\kappa_4+ \sqrt{\kappa_{6}}}}\right],
$$
the recovered densities shift around significantly.

And I agree with the authors that the inclusion of high order cumulant ($\kappa_4$ and $\kappa_6$) is valid in theory because the objective density functions of many Lévy processes for short maturity $T$ (in which I use $T=1/252$), exhibit sharp peaks and fat tails. **But**, in my numerical example, I find that the values of $\kappa_4$ and $\kappa_6$ are extremely small, up to $10^{-21}$ and $10^{-33}$. Hence, the two truncation ranges: $[a_{4}, b_{4}]$ and $[a_{6}, b_{6}]$ are almost identical. So, intuitively speaking, the recovered densities should be similar. In contrast, my numerical results reflect that the recovered density is highly sensitive to the inclusion of high-order cumulants:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And the following graph plots the coefficient vector $\boldsymbol{A}=\left(A_{k}\right)_{k=1}^{N}$, which is calculated as:
$$
A_{k}=\frac{2}{b-a}\Re\left\{\Phi\left(\frac{k\pi}{b-a}\right)\exp\left\{-i\left(\frac{ak\pi}{b-a}\right)\right\}\right\}.
$$
[image]
And one can observe that the real part of the characteristic function has a relatively slow decay if the truncation range $[a_{6}, b_{6}]$ is selected.

Are there any suggestions to remedy this? I am currently working on the standard deviation (i.e. $\sqrt{\kappa_{2}}$)-scaled version of my objective density. Besides, I think FFT is another choice but the short-maturity pdf has significant fat tails. Hence, one should expect a slow decay of the real part of the characteristic function which will render the Gibbs phenomenon as pointed out by [Fallahgoul et al. (2022)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3327137).

P.S. Confusion around the truncation range is not new. There are several discussions on this technical topic such as [Floc’h (2020)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.13248) and [Junike and Pankrashkin (2021)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.01030v4). But I do not think their solutions are applicable when the model gets complicated (such as multi-factor affine).

I am willing to show the codes if necessary.

Comment: If you are looking at such extremely short timescales, I'd expext the density will limit to a constant vol. Just use BS at that point....?